# Get FaceTime email address from iOS contact book

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

I was researching ABAddressBook, ABPerson etc, but I am unable to find it. Is there an option of getting a user's email address associated with FaceTime from the address book?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this questions? :)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately i didnt find anything.

Comment: Thanks for response if I find out I'll post the answer.